# I keep getting "double cannot be dereferenced" in Java

Tags: java, macos

I have to write a program that records 12 months of profit for 5 different shops in a 2D array. I made the constructor to take the input of the profits. I when I try to compile, there's an issue in my totalProfit method. It says 'double cannot be dereferenced' and highlight the .length part of my first for loop.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Profits
{
    static private double[][] profit=new double[5][12];
    private Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please input your profits, each month at a time.");
        Profits year11=new Profits();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(profit));
    }
    public Profits(){
        for(int b=0; b<profit.length; b++){
            for(int m=0; m<profit[0].length; m++){
                profit[b][m]=in.nextDouble();
            }
        }    
    }
    public double totalProfit(){
        double profit=0.0;
        for(int b=0; b<profit.length; b++){
            for(int m=0; m<profit[0].length; m++){
                profit+=profit[b][m];
            }
        }  
        return profit;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 8):

You have declared a local variable of type `double` with the same name as `double[][]` array.

```
double profit=0.0;
```

The variable `profit` now hides the instance variable.

- Either change the name of the variable - preferable.
- Or qualify the access to `profit` array with `this` -> `this.profit.length`,  `this.profit[0].length` - just to complete the answer.